# Replacing files with infected files on anonymous ftp server

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management, pgp, gnupg

I am creating a new question as i now have another question which was raised from a previous answered question post.

What im trying to figure out is would this scenario be possible.

I have an anonymous FTP server with a file that we will call cred.gpg, within that encrypted file is a PDF named passwords.pdf.

Would it be possible, as its an anonymous server for someone to remove cred.gpg. Then for them to create a bogus file on their side which contains a virus named passwords.pdf and encrypt it using my public key to a file name cred.gpg.

Then upload that file to the server.  Then when i go to open the file it all looks the same except when i go to open the passwords.pdf i am now infected.

Would this scenario be possible?  I am thinking it is, but im not sure, i just need advice on whether this would be possible, as i may need to rethink my setup.

Thanks

Comment: Definitely a possibility, actually.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible,  if your server accepts files uploaded by an anonymous user and if you don't provide a hash (e.g. SHA-256, SHA-512,...) in order to check that cred.gpg actually contains passwords.pdf and not evilfile.pdf.

Comment: Wouldn't the OP detect a problem when they go to decrypt cred.gpg?

Comment: What kind of problem? If evilfile.pdf can be correctly opened by a file viewer (despite being malicious), I don't see how OP could detect something suspicious.

Comment: You're right. I was confused about whether symmetric or asymmetric encryption was being used.

Comment: This answer is not partially correct, which means it's also partially wrong. Absent hashing, key validation is better trusted via fingerprinting

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this based on how PGP/GPG works. So you have a file for say Client X, and you are using FTP as a delivery mechanism. You want to ensure that your data is protected (encrypted) and only Client X can read it. To do so, you would be using your PGP key for signing, and they will use their key for decrypting.

```
You (PGP key which can be looked up on a PGP key server) --> Encrypt --> Them (decrypt)
```

Your PGP key generates a fingerprint which can be looked up. The key to it all is, ensuring Client X receives YOUR fingerprint to which THEY will have to verify. For example, if you list your specific key, here is how to get your fingerprint:

```
gpg --list-keys johndoe@mycompany
pub   dsa1024/1DBD1234 2011-10-05 [expires: 2021-10-02]
uid         [ultimate] VALIDATION (TESTING) <johndoe@mycompany>
sub   elg4096/12347B3C 2011-10-05 [expires: 2021-10-02]
```

Fingerprint

```
gpg --fingerprint 1DBD1234
pub   dsa1024/1DBD1234 2011-10-05 [expires: 2021-10-02]
      Key fingerprint = 1234 EECF B9C4 6D0C 154A  5678 4B2B DE74 1DBD 9876
uid         [ultimate] VALIDATION (TESTING) <johndoe@mycompany>
sub   elg4096/12347B3C 2011-10-05 [expires: 2021-10-02]
```

You can then have Client X verify your key based on [fingerprint matches](https://help.gnome.org/users/seahorse/stable/misc-key-fingerprint.html.en). So let's see how I can get by this as an attacker. As an attacker, I have to know who the file is destined for. I would need to encrypt my malware pretending to be you. But how can I "spoof/mimic" your fingerprint? I can't. I can try to install a keystroke logger, wait for you to enter your password, steal your public and private key. If this happens, you have a lot more problems to contend with. **BUT**... I can generate my own PGP/GPG key pretending to be you, upload it to a GPG/PGP keyserver, sign ANYTHING pretending to be you. If the recipient does NOT verify the fingerprint, they are done.